# Delphi videos in any other format than flash?

Tags: delphi

Everyone knows about there instructional videos http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Videos but I want to watch them on my iPad when I go on vacation.

The problem is the videos are in swf and will not play on my iPad.  Does any know of another source for these videos in another format?

Thanks.

Comment: why dont you convert the files to a compatible format for the iPad?

Comment: Go to superuser.com and ask how to watch swf files on an iPad.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that not everyone knows about those videos. It would be a blast if almost 7 x 10^9 people would know about those videos ;-P

Comment: Complain to Apple, and have them fix it :-)

Answer (score 1):

For the moment flash video is the container of choice for most video content on the internet. Saif is right. If you want those specific videos you'll need to convert them yourself. There are several decent flv to mp4 converters available for free (Miro comes to mind). SWF is takes a bit more [work](http://www.ehow.com/how_4447326_extract-video-swf-files.html) to extract the video content.

Now if you are looking for Delphi content that's already available in MPEG 4 you can try http://edn.embarcadero.com/tv. The content from the most recent Coderage event is available as an mp4 download.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them into a proper format using a free video convert like [Any Video Converter](http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/)

Answer (score 0):

I've had reasonable success watching on-line Flash content on my iPad using [iOSFlashVideo](http://iosflashvideo.fw.hu/).
Not tried it on off-line flash files though.

--jeroen